# Change in database table reflects immediately in datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datagrid

I am checking whether there are existing solutions/ procedures for the following scenario.
When there is a change in a row of database table, the same should reflect immediately in datagrid that i have in winform on a push basis but not in timely refresh basis. If it has to be refresh basis, i dont want the user selections of datagrid to disappear.

i guess, i can do this by signalR in case of webforms. But in case of winforms or asp.net, please point me to any appropriate tutorials to do this.

Thanks

Comment: I would post as an answer but SO frowns on link only answers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If this is the actual problem - *i dont want the user selections of datagrid to disappear* - then solution is easy: keep selection (store/restore) before updating table.

Comment: @Sinatr How is that a push solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the datasource on the save button itself.  Then, it will be refelcted immediately after you commit the changes in the row and save it.